# vuejs code splitting and lighthouse performance

Tags: vue.js, webpack, lighthouse

I've a fairly big webapp with blog / sites and a webshop and I wrote my components that way that I always have a user and an admin component.

For example the template of a text component looks like this

```
const admin-text = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "admin" */ ./admin/text.vue)
import user-text from './user.vue'

admin-text(v-if="auth_isAdmin(user)")
user-text(v-else)
```

The admin chunk is only marked as prefetch, and when opening the network panel in chrome I don't see the admin chunk downloaded, HOWEVER if I run lighthouse it seems to also download that chunk because I get only a 82 performance score and the warning to AVOID enormous network payloads and it list's a few chunks that I don't see on the network panel.

Now I'm not sure if that approach to code splitting really works, or why is lighthouse also downloading those chunks marked as prefetch which shouldn't even be downloaded?

Comment: Lighthouse pushes me use prefetch as it says it is optimization opportunity, but I am able to see those chunks in network tab, maybe you filtered them? ‍♂️